# I want to select a query which would give me a Unique dates and Max(value) within the multiple dates rows

Tags: sql-server

I want to select a unique dates from multiple rows and the rows having max(value) from another column.

SQL Table

```
DateTime        Value
01-06-2019  100
01-06-2019  200
02-06-2019  300
03-06-2019  400
04-06-2019  1000
```

Result I want

```
Jun-01  200
Jun-02  400
Jun-03  1000


SELECT tt.*
FROM [dbo].[device_Flow_Data_Json] tt
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT Created_date, MAX(Instant_Flow) AS Instant_Flow
    FROM [dbo].[device_Flow_Data_Json] 
    GROUP BY Created_date) groupedtt 
ON tt.Created_date = groupedtt.Created_date 
AND tt.Instant_Flow = groupedtt.Instant_Flow
 where groupedtt.Created_date between '2019-07-01 14:09:36.040' and '2019-07-11 14:09:36.040'
```

I am getting a result which is having all rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Foe your above given example

table data

```
2019-07-01 10
2019-07-01 200
2019-07-01 2000
2019-07-02 200
2019-07-03 400
2019-07-05 600
```

query :- `SELECT date,max(value) as value FROM`datacheck`GROUP by date`

result is :

```
2019-07-01 2000
2019-07-02 200
2019-07-03 400
2019-07-05 600
```

In above query you can group by date and in select  use max function.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for a subquery here. This can be simply done as:

```
SELECT DateTime,
       MAX([Value]) AS MaxValue
FROM YourTable YT
GROUP BY DateTime;
```

So, I assume, for your query that'll be:

```
SELECT dFD.DateTime,
       MAX(dFD.[Value]) AS MaxValue
FROM [dbo].[device_Flow_Data_Json] dFD
WHERE dFD.Created_date BETWEEN '2019-07-01T14:09:36.040' AND'2019-07-11T14:09:36.040'
GROUP BY dFD.DateTime
```

Comment: Tried with your solution but it gives me multiple rows for date like below,                                                         Created_date        MaxValue
01-07-2019 14:09 2267.09
01-07-2019 14:09 7186
01-07-2019 14:10 2311.69
01-07-2019 14:10 4173
01-07-2019 14:10 1889.17
01-07-2019 14:11 6737
01-07-2019 14:11 1963.36

Comment: SELECT Created_date,
       MAX(Instant_Flow) AS MaxValue
FROM [dbo].[device_Flow_Data_Json] where Created_date between '2019-07-01 14:09:36.040' and '2019-07-11 14:09:36.040'

GROUP BY Created_date;

Comment: This gives me multiple row dates with duplicate i just want only one and max of values from them.

Comment: Your sample data doesn't have any times in your values @SagarShendarkar... If you have times in your data, why are you not supplying relevant sample data? The answer is correct for the sample data you supplied; i can't help you if you don't supply relevant samples.

Comment: solved my problem converted datetime to date and then made operations.